# 「/var/log/nginx/error.log」のファイル内容に記載されている日時が合っているか確認したい

Tags: centos, nginx

**/var/log/nginx/error.logのファイル内容のエラー項目日時は何に基づいているのでしょうか？**
・合っているか確認するためにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

> 2018/03/10 18:19:08 [error] ××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××
>   2018/03/11 16:16:26 [error] ××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx

---

**追記分**

確認日時
・2018/3/12

ファイル名
・error.log-20180312

ファイル最終更新日時
・2018/3/11 16:00:00

ファイルに記載された最新内容

> 2018/03/11 16:00:00 [error] 10680#10680: *63 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 多分、何かのIPアドレス, server: localhost, request: "GET
>   //MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "IPアドレス"

・質問主旨としては、ファイルの最終更新日時がOSのシステム日時に基づく？ のだとしたら、Nginxエラー内容に記載されている時間は何に基づくのか知りたい、というものです
・Nginxには、何か日時を合わせるような設定はあるでしょうか？

Comment: 基本は「エラーとなるイベントが発生したタイミング」かと思いますが、どんなエラーなのかが分かる程度にログの詳しい内容を記載してもらった方が回答が付きやすいかと。ユーザ名やファイル名などのセンシティブな情報は伏せてもらって構いませんが、今書かれている情報はざっくり過ぎます。

Comment: 日時はエラー発生時刻が出ていると思いますが、確認方法としてはエラーログが出るようなエラーをご自身の操作により再現してログに出力された時間と一致するかどうかを確認したらよいかと思います。

Comment: ログファイルのタイムスタンプと、最後に出力されたログの日時を比較すれば、大まかにですがずれているかどうかは確認出来ると思いますが。

Comment: @cubic。エラー内容追記しました

Comment: ＠Sugiyama Koichi。ログファイルのタイムスタンプと、最後に出力されたログの日時が一致しているのですが、ということはどういうことでしょうか？　時間は合っているということ？？

Comment: だとしたら、Nginxエラーの時間はシステム時間だということですね。